# Cisco ISR with Windows L2TP VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, cisco, l2tp

I have a Server 2012 box running PPTP and L2TP VPN services behind a Cisco 1841 ISR.  My NAT rules allow the PPTP traffic to connect, however I cannot complete a connection with L2TP.  The relevant NAT rules are below:

```
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.62.2 500 1.2.3.4 500 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.62.2 1701 1.2.3.4 1701 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.62.2 1723 1.2.3.4 1723 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.62.2 4500 1.2.3.4 4500 extendable
```

Is there something else I need to enable on the 1841?  I tried turning on ESP and allowing isakmp and esp via access-lists.  However the first access-list rule should allow that all through anyway, so no I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure it's PPTP that is working and L2TP failing and not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

PPTP has nothing to do with L2TP. PPTP uses gre to transport payload and *tcp/1723* as control channel, while L2TP uses *udp/1701* as single channel, that can be further encrypted by the ipsec. By the way, Windows out-of-the-box does enforce ipsec on L2TP.

Thus your NAT settings have nothing to do with L2TP/ipsec you are trying to pass through your gateway, because you should pass *udp/500* and *ah/esp* protocols (the latter does depend on the security policy that Windows VPN hub is enforcing, and AH won't work though NAT at all). Furthermore, having a VPN hub behind a Cisco gateway that you control is a ***total nonsense***, because Cisco is capable of *both dot1q encapsulation **and** VPN termination*, including l2tp with or without ipsec. So either give your Windows VPN hub full WAN connectivity via vlan, or configure the VPN server on the Cisco.

Comment: I think he knows that PPTP has nothing to do with L2TP, he's just saying that he has configured both and one is working while the other is not. He has udp/500 (ike) and udp/4500 (ipsec over UDP) configured, so that should be sufficient for L2TP/IPsec to work, because of NAT-T. Which is why I suspected that maybe L2TP/IPsec is working ok, and PPTP is failing, since indeed (as you say) PPTP uses GRE in addition to tcp/1723